# Div width wont resize with scaled image

Tags: html, css, sass

I scaled an img down using width percentage to better fit the screen, however the parent divs width did not scale to wrap the img.

HTML

```
<div class="game-container">
  <div class="game-table">
    <img src="../../assets/img/table-top.png" class="table-image">
    <div class="table-cards">
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/blue_back.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/gray_back.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/green_back.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/red_back.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/purple_back.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.game-container {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.game-table {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.table-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.table-cards {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: aqua 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}

.card-holder {
  border: blueviolet 3px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  width: 35%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: red 3px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

RESULT
[Image to show the current layout](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e3zTOBiAddaVZQvU2jHaJWzzVghwe2j_/view?usp=sharing)

I would Like the card-holder div (purple) to fit to the card (red)

WHAT I TRIED

I have tried changing the display of card and card-holder to inline-block. I also tried keeping card width as the default and changing the card-holder width and scale instead. However neither worked.

Thank You!

Comment: Try giving parent div's height and width as auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Border was causing the problem. I removed border of the image(.card) and it worked as expected.
thanks

```css
.game-container {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.game-table {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.table-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.table-cards {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: aqua 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}

.card-holder {
  border: blueviolet 3px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  width: 35%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* border: red 3px solid; */
  display: inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-container">
  <div class="game-table">
    <img src="../../assets/img/table-top.png" class="table-image">
    <div class="table-cards">
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/blue_back.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/gray_back.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/green_back.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/red_back.png">
      </div>
      <div class="card-holder">
        <img class="card" src="../../assets/img/cards/purple_back.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```